# Steganography using audio stream

Tags: audio

I am working on a project that is audio steganography and i need any new scheme along with its implementation. My input is text that will be encoded in the audio file. I want some suggestion on new encoding scheme related to phase coding. I have thought of using the complete intial phase to hide the text to increase the data transmission. Can anyone help me with the code.

Comment: Are you looking to hire someone to write code for you?  Show us what you've written so far, and we'll help you if you run into a roadblock.  If you're asking for general algorithms, you may have better luck in one of the sister sites that discuss those specifics.  Voting to close as not an existing software problem.

Comment: You need *any* new scheme AND its implementation? Looking for "some suggestion on new encoding scheme"? All this screams too broad and opinionated. And you want some help with the code, but you haven't shown us any. Have you read the FAQ? (Not on a computer, too incovenient to link to it at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technical paper where professionals describe methods of Audio Steganography:

http://airccse.org/journal/jma/3311ijma08.pdf